# Is this a known ordering algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was doing some practicing and implemented some well known order algorithms, and I thought that if we look at the list sideways it should appear sorted without doing any work (See code, it's pretty self explanatory). Pretty sure it's already thought of/done and I would like to know what its actually called.

This is how I implemented it. And I know it will function poorly when the content "max-min" range is large and whouls probably only work nicely on integers. (But it looks to function extremely nicely on very large lists where the content is from a somewhat small range (less than 110000000 variations on my PC (mem started saying no)

The main reason for getting the name of this is to look at further improvements and variations:

```
void MainWindow(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 130000000; a++)
    {
        rList.Add(rand.Next(1, 110000000));
    }
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SortYAxis(rList);
    });
}

void SortYAxis(List<int> list)
{
    int max = int.MinValue;
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (int a in list)//Get max/min range
    {
        if (max < a)
        {
            max = a;
        }
        else if (min > a)
        {
            min = a;
        }
    }

    int[] yList = new int[max - min + 1];
    foreach (int a in list)//Flatten along Y axis
    {
        yList[a - min]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0, a = 0; i < yList.Length; i++)//Read down Y axis
    {
        while (yList[i] != 0)
        {
            list[a++] = i + min;
            yList[i]--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what is this type called? I'm pretty sure it has a name like all other types of algorithms.

Comment: Oh, it's called bucket sort, and yes - when the range is not big it performs O(n) which is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).  (Your code is pretty much the textbook implementation.)

Bucket sort's efficiency comes from the fact that it is not a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) - the elements of the array are not compared to each other.  This is how bucket sort can have O(n) complexity, and "beat" the standard O(n log(n)) limit that comparison sorts are constrained to.

The drawback (as you surmised) is that bucket sort only works on a finite set, i.e. there must be some finite number of "buckets" that can be created to hold any of the elements being sorted.  Therefore, bucket sort cannot be used as a sorting algorithm for floating point values or strings.  Furthermore, bucket sort has a high space requirement if the "range" of values is large.  These factors tend to outweigh the benefits of linear complexity, so bucket sort doesn't tend to get used much.

Comment: no worries, you can give it to BJ - I like his name :D

Comment: @Thomas I was typing my answer when alfasin posted his comment - didn't see it until after I was done.  If he posts it as an answer you can accept his.

Comment: Never heard of bucket sort actually. is it a commonly used solution?

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian well known - yes, but I don't think it's common. Not sure why though.

Comment: It's algorithmic complexity is better than comparison-based sorts, so it can be useful for large integral data sets.  But it can't be used as a sorting algorithm for floating point numbers or strings, which is the main reason it doesn't get a lot of visibility.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe you should clarify how integers are a finite set :P

Comment: @JuanLopes Rounded out my answer a bit.  Thanks for the suggestion.